# Python - Turn nested list into a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a nested list which contains various types of crimes. To clarify, `crimeDescription` is formatted as such: 
`[['Murder'], ['Assault'], ... , ['Stalking'], ['Rape']]`. I am looking to create a dictionary that will hold every value/crime that is in this list and record its frequency, or how often it appears in the data set. Since the keys inside dictionaries can't be lists, I am attempting to access the string inside of each nested list, by calling its index i[0] in the for loop. When I run the following program:

```
#TypesOfCrime --> a List containing all different types of crime that's happened in LA

TypesOfCrime = []
CrimeFreq = {}
for i in crimeDescription: 
    if i not in TypesOfCrime:
        i = i[0]
        CrimeFreq[i] = 1
    elif i in TypesOfCrime:
        i = i[0]
        CrimeFreq[i] += 1
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-a8698e79e96a> in <module>()
      5     if i not in TypesOfCrime:
      6         TypesOfCrime.append(i)
----> 7         CrimeFreq[i[0]] = 1
      8     elif i in TypesOfCrime:
      9         CrimeFreq[i[0]] += 1

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I create a dictionary containing each different value that is in my nested list? Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Um, is there any good reason you have a list of single-element lists? Also, that error message is not consistent with the example code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is just how I received the data set. I would love to mutate the content in any way that would be helpful, and that is what I am trying to do in the if statements, but getting this TypeError... any ideas?

Comment: what is `crimeDescription`, is it just a string describing each `TypesOfCrime`?

Comment: @downshift crimeDescription is a nested list containing the various types of crime, formatted like: [['Murder'], ['Assault'], ... , ['Stalking'], ['Rape']]. Therefore, crimeDescription[0][0] == 'Murder' . Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: Also, look at the `defaultdict` in the `collections` module to simplify your code.

Comment: thanks @user7366442, can you re-define `TypesOfCrime` as  `TypesOfCrime =  ['Murder', 'Assault', 'Stalking', 'Rape']`?

Comment: What does `TypesofCrime` look like?  Is it formatted like `crimeDescription`?

Comment: The code in your example is not the same as in the traceback. Show us the real code and the correct input.

Answer (score 0):

To count something with a dict, check if the key already exists and then increment the value, otherwise add the key with value 1:

```
crime_freq = {}

for current_crime in crimeDescription:
    crime = current_crime[0]
    if crime in crime_freq:
        crime_freq[crime] += 1
    else:
        crime_freq[crime] = 1
```

The modern way to solve your problem is to use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a generator expression:

```
crime_freq = collections.Counter(crime[0] for crime in crimeDescription)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to if key not existence, created value OR if key existence, add value.

I recommendation using setdefault() method.

```
crime_freq = {}

for current_crime in crimeDescription:
    crime = current_crime[0]
    crime_freq.setdefault(crime, 0)
    crime_freq[crime] += 1
```

If using setdefault() method, code is simple.

I usually using setdefault() method frequently.